# How to assign a list of colors to a specific bar in a stacked bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I have a stacked bar chart showing the count of different comorbidities grouped by sex.

Female is represented by `'pink'`, Male by `'lightskyblue'`.

To make it more obvious that `'None'` is not just another comorbidity, I want `'None'` (patient had no comorbidity) to use a different set of colors to make it stand out: `'lightcoral'` for Female and `'royalblue'` for Male.

This is my current stacked bar chart using `colors = ['lightskyblue', 'pink']`:

```
comorbidity_counts_by_gender = df.groupby('sex_female')[comorbidity_columns].sum()

comorbidity_counts_by_gender = comorbidity_counts_by_gender[comorbidity_counts_by_gender.sum().sort_values(ascending=True).index].T

colors = ['lightskyblue', 'pink']
bars = comorbidity_counts_by_gender.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(8, 8), color=colors, width=0.8)

plt.title('Distribution of Comorbidities by Gender')
plt.xlabel('Count')
plt.ylabel('')
bars.legend(title='Gender', loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), frameon=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

No matter what I try, I can't seem to provide a different pair of colors to the 'None' bar. Here are a 2 ways I tried to solve the issue that didn't work out for me:

**Try 1:**

```
colors = [['royalblue', 'lightcoral'] if comorbidity == 'None' else ['lightskyblue', 'pink'] for comorbidity in comorbidity_counts_per_gender.index]
```

This results in ValueError: Invalid color ['lightskyblue', 'pink']

**Try 2:**

```
colors = []
for comorbidity in comorbidity_counts_by_gender.index:
  if comorbidity == 'None':
    colors = ['royalblue', 'lightcoral']
  else:
    colors = ['lightskyblue', 'pink']
```

This always uses ['lightskyblue', 'pink'] for any column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that changes the colours of the appropriate bars directly:

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def setcolors(ax, name="None", colors=["royalblue", "lightcoral"]):
    """
    Function to set the colours for the bars for a given category name.
    """

    # get labels
    ytl = ax.get_yticklabels()
    numlabels = len(ytl)
    
    # find the index of the given named label
    for i, t in enumerate(ytl):
        if t.get_text() == name:
            break
    
    # get the matplotlib rectangle objects representing the bars
    # (note this relies on nothing else having been added to the plot)
    rects = ax.get_children()[0:2 * numlabels]
    nrects = [rects[i], rects[numlabels + i]]
    
    # loop over the two bars for the given named label and change the colours
    for rect, color in zip(nrects, colors):
        rect.set_color(color)
        rect.set_edgecolor("none")


# some mock data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Male": [5, 1, 3, 1],
        "Female": [4, 2, 2, 0]
    },
    index=["Smoking", "Hypertension", "None", "Hyperthyroidism"],
)

bars = df.plot(kind="barh", stacked=True, color=["lightskyblue", "pink"])

# change the colors
setcolors(bars)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that, by default (*I think*) the [`Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) objects representing the bars should be the first things in the list returned by `get_children()`. But, if you add further things to the plot then this *may* not be the case.